# How to program an MSP430 chip on a launchboard with no IC holder

Tags: microcontroller, msp430

Our university provides MSP-EXP430FR4133 LaunchPad Development Kits like the one shown in this picture :

[image]

Although this doesn't have a slot to program an IC like these ones do:

[image]

I was wondering if it's possible to program an IC such as the MSP430G2231IPW14 using the development kits of our university? And if so how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

This would be easier to explain with a larger picture, but yes; the Launchpad boards are nicely designed into a "program" and "target" section with connectors between them. So, provided you can build a replacement "target" which you want to program, you should be able to remove the jumpers on the Launchpad and connect the program section to your target. For a DIP package it ought to be possible to do this on a breadboard. Keep the wires between the two as short as possible.

I believe the minimum set of pins that must be connected is power, ground, SBWTCK and SBWTIO - this gives you the "single wire debug" interface.